# OpenID Connect: PKCE vs Back-channel Authorization Code

Tags: security, oauth-2.0, single-sign-on, openid-connect, pkce

**Question**: I believe I understand the improvements PKCE makes over implicit flow, but what're the fundamental differences in security between the user's machine using PKCE vs an authorisation code flow where an app receives & processes the authorisation code on the back-end?

---

**Background**:
Our team's been looking to add / implement single sign-on across a mix of different products. These include an older website with a login form / cookies, an SPA/PWA currently using symmetric JWTs, and a desktop application plugin also using JWTs. We were priced out of Auth0, and so are looking to leverage OpenID Connect via MS &/or Google sign-in.

As a trial, we've gotten the "authorisation code grant flow" working with the regular web-app. I.e. The user is redirected to an MS/Google login that they complete, are redirected back with an authorisation code, our server receives the authoristion code, and we exchange that alongside our client secret to get their ID Token. At that point we can verify who they are & we can just log them in with cookies as normal.

The dev looking at the SPA component used a library that by default uses a PKCE flow, so the client themselves ended up with their ID Token, and could then send it to us for JWT validation. The process for validating the JWT doesn't seem too involved, but it did make me question why wouldn't just want to receive an authorization code from them? I looked at some example implementations, and when using the non-PKCE Authorisation Code flow, some libraries were just trusting the ID Token it received from Microsoft, since the endpoint was known to the app beforehand / not configurable by the end user.